# How do I form a nice circle area given a lot of hexagons (Civ5 figures)?

Tags: geometry

My current approach was given a fixed radius find a set of neighboring hexagons and then filter them based on a distance between (center point of a 'center hexagon') to a center point of each hexagon, but the result looks ugly (my circle isn't really that smooth):
[image]

---

It looks way better for NYC, though:
[[image]]

---

If I use the different approach: include a hexagon iif all the **distance(center point of a center hexagon, vertex of other hexagon) <= radius)** the results are slightly better: 
[image]

---

If I include a hexagon if **distance(center point of a center hexagon, at least 1 vertex of other hexagon) <= radius)** the result is worse: 
[image]

Comment: How is the distance computed?

Comment: Based on http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/inverse.pdf (using the "Inverse Formula" (section 4)).